# Multi-line select component for react?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a decent react component that implements a multi-line select box, i.e. not a dropdown, but rather only the dropped down part of a dropdown. It should behave similar to a plain html `<select size=n>...</select>` but I would like to provide a custom render method for the elements. Cannot find anything :/